# Can't get the geopoint when there is no record in table

Tags: mysql, laravel, geospatial

When I use

```
'geopoint' => DB::raw('POINT('.$data['lat'].', '.$data['lng'].')')
```

it is working however it is vulnerable for SQLInjection. So I use

```
'geopoint' => DB::select("SELECT POINT(?, ?) as point FROM my_table", [$data['lng'], $data['lat']])[0]->point
```

but this one doesn't return the point when the table is empty but when I create a row in the table manually, it is working...

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: use `COALESCE()`

Comment: Why would you expect _anything_ to be returned from a query against an empty table?  Off the top of my head, maybe the statement isn't being prepared correctly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually I want the mysql function which is `POINT` here. I can't do it in laravel, can I? So I don't want it to return any value but I want to use the functionality of mysql to get a geopoint type value. And then to insert that value fetched from that query to a table.

Answer (score 0):

It will return 0 if no record :

```
DB::select("SELECT COALESCE(POINT(?, ?),0) as point FROM my_table", [$data['lng'], $data['lat']])[0]->point
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

> only get one record

```
 DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT POINT(:lat , :lng) as point FROM my_table"), ['lat' => $data['lng'],'lng' => $data['lat']])[0]->point
```